# Returning from second call in completed future

Tags: java, spring

Suppose i have two functions

```
CompletableFuture<datatype1> func_A;
CompletableFuture<datatype2> func_B;
```

I want to write a third function so as to

> **return func_A(args)**

after executing

> funcB(args)

```
CompletableFuture<datatype1> func_C(args) {
    return completedFuture(null)
        .thencompose(__ -> func_B(args))
        .thencompose(__ -> func_A(args));
}
```

Is this the right way to do that?

Comment: Please take a bit of time to learn how to properly use the markdown formatting here, especially when providing code examples. That preview and help information right there on the editor exists for a reason ...

Comment: Right way in what sense? It's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: I want the return from func_A but only after the execution of funct_B
but both functions are completableFuture<>. So I am asking if the code logic that I have written will give me the correct response?

Comment: 1. According to the provided code, `func_A` and `func_B` are not functions but `CompletableFuture` objects. 2. `func_C ` is not a correct Java function definition (argument type is missing). 3. completedFuture(null) is useless